# how to recover my hard drive...put an iso image on it with dd

Tags: dd

I did the following:

```
dd if=some.iso of=/dev/sda
```

Or some such craziness.  How should I recover from this?  Gparted, etc..., didn't help out, deleting partition etc...  Whenever I try to install a linux onto this disc it complains that its an iso9660 cd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero out at least the first track of sectors, and you should be okay.

> dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda  count=63

Seagate and WD have CDs of utilities that can also do this.
This will force the writing of a clean Master Boot Record, MBR, by the next installer you use.  Some full-disk recovery programs work best by zeroing out the beginning of the disk before performing the installation.